# $_POST empty after ajax post called

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, post

So the purpose of me using this ajax post is to use some JS variables in a wordpress loop, so I can call a custom loop depending on what the variables are in the ajax post.

Below is the ajax call.

```
$('.collection-more').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://tmet.dev/wp-content/themes/muban-trust/single-collection.php',
        data: { "test" : "hello" },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    });
})
```

Currently I'm sending hard-coded data.

In my single-collection.php page:

```
    <?php 
    print_r($_POST);


    if(isset($POST['filters[Artist]']))
    {
        $filters_obj = $_POST['filters[Artist]'];
        $filters_array = json_decode($filters_obj, TRUE);

        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($filters_array); $i++)
        {
            echo '<p>h'.$obj->name.'</p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

I'm using the print_r just to debug the problem, currently it returns:

Array()

The problem is that I cannot access the Json object called "test" within the single-collection.php

How do I access it?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Screenshot of firebug
[image]

Comment: Add .done() and.error() to $.ajax just to make sure No errors, change post to POST

Comment: The `print_r` looks correct. It says `[test] => hello`.

Comment: Barma +1. I see no error here... Looks like POST data is there.

Comment: The print_r only returns the value on firebug, in the html it just shows Array().

Comment: The print_r result in the GET doesn't mean anything. What's the Response in the POST request?

Comment: @user3876596 Firebug is showing what the PHP script actually printed. So `$_POST` is _not_ empty. I don't know what you mean about the HTML -- your AJAX code doesn't put the response in HTML, it just uses `console.log`.

Comment: The response of the POST is here: http://i.imgur.com/jGJdhza.jpg

Comment: If $_POST is not empty why does it echo an empty array in the HTML: http://i.imgur.com/IyyIjGI.jpg

Comment: Also if the $_POST is not empty, I guess it means I am accessing it wrong. What is the correct way to access it?

My aim is to get the data that is in $POST['varName'] and use that is a custom wordpress loop.

Comment: So I guess $_POST wasnt empty afterall, Thanks for opening my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

**From ajax to php :**
this is the conventional way

```
var payload = {
      smth1: "name",
      smth2: "age"
    };
```

and then when calling ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: "somephp.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: payload,
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true
            })
```

**From phpPost to javascript:**

right way getting the post parameters:

```
$fields = $_POST['fields'];
$usernameGiven = $fields['smth1'];
$passwordGiven = $fields['smth2'];
```

and when returning smthn to javascript

```
$result = array(
             "something" => "something",
             "something2" => $something2

         );

         echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: The question is about sending parameters from JS to PHP, not about returning from PHP to JS.

Comment: user is saying that 'print_r($_POST);' returns empty array() means his post data is not reaching the script

Comment: Your JS is essentially the same as in the original post. All you did was assign the object literal to a variable, but that shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: And there is no difference in making array payload and using it in data paramtere, or creating anonymous array. This is not the source of problem.

Comment: @Barmar i just wanted to show the big picture of javascript<->php posting stuff. by looking at the answer he will see his obvious error : `$_POST['filters[Artist]']` imo.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_POST['test']` to access the `test` parameter. Your `print_r()` shows that it is filled in correctly.

Your PHP code is accessing `$_POST['filters[Artist]']` but there is no such parameter in the Javascript. If you pass:

```
data: { 'filters[Artist]': somevalue }
```

you can access it in PHP as `$_POST['filters']['Artist']`.